# Everything is ok, but my 127.0.0.1:8000 can't show anything, why ? I used django-sphinx

Tags: python, django, sphinx, django-sphinx

```
from djangosphinx.models import SphinxSearch
def xx(request):
    queryset =File.search.query('test')
    #return HttpResponse(queryset)#<------1
    return render_to_response('a.html',{'a':queryset})#<--------2
```

and

```
class File(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=200) # We actually store tags for efficiency in tag,tag,tag format here

    objects = models.Manager()
    search  = SphinxSearch(index="test1")
```

a.html:

```
{% for i in a %}
    Some value: {{i}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you please rephrase the question in a manner that is more understandable? Posting the error seen, adding log file output etc are some ways to help people on SO understand what could've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not giving a lot of info, I will make a educated guess. You probably didn't build you search index. Try building it before quering, sphynx search in the sindex, not in the DB.